# Simple way to call asmx web service from another asmx web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I am using asmx webservice  in my asp.net web application. For some case 
I need to call the client's asmx webservice  from my own webservice. what is the simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this post [Calling webservice from another websservice](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/718fc8/calling-a-web-service-into-another-web-service-application/)

Basically, you will have to reference the second webservice from the first one and it would be similar to calling any other webservice.

Comment: I could not use add web reference , because client url should be changed with respect to the different client. Only my own webservice is static one. I will communicate different client url based on the input.